# CreateProcess() failed when specifying service restart command in puppet

Tags: windows, puppet

Running puppet on 64bit windows 2008 i have a service which looks like the following:

```
service{'Tomcat7':
    ensure => running,
    restart => 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file C:\tomcat7\bin\RestartService.ps1',
}
```

Running the command after restart in command prompt works

However:

When puppet triggers the refresh i get the following:

```
Debug: Executing 'c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file c:\tomcat7\bin\RestartService.ps1'
Error: /Stage[main]/Dep7transcription/Service[Tomcat7]: Failed to call refresh: CreateProcess() failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error: /Stage[main]/Dep7transcription/Service[Tomcat7]: CreateProcess() failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could be file system redirection.  Try `c:\windows\sysnative\...` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this comes up again this is related to inconsistent treatment of whitespace - arguments cannot be passed to the service restart command as of the puppet version up to date at time of asking

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the backslahses in forward slashes. Ruby internally uses the forward slash as path separator on all platforms.